# How to establish a TCP connection in python between client and sever python

Tags: python

Below is my client.py code for a TCP connection with server,

```py
import socket 
import sys, datetime
import select, threading

def send_message(sock, message):
    sock.sendall(message.encode())

def receive_message(sock):
    data = sock.recv(1024)
    return data.decode().strip()

def user_input(sock):
    while True:
        command = input("")
        if command == ":Exit":
            send_message(sock, ":Exit\n")
            break
            #sock.close()
            #sys.exit(0)
        elif command == ":)":
            send_message(sock, "[feeling happy]\n")
        elif command == ":(":
            send_message(sock, "[feeling sad]\n")
        elif command == ":mytime":
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            send_message(sock, now.strftime("It's %H:%M on %a, %d %b, %Y.") + '\n')
        elif command.startswith(":dm"):
            send_message(sock, "IDK how to code this")
        else:
            send_message(sock, command + '\n')


def main():
    server_host = sys.argv[1]
    server_port = int(sys.argv[2])
    password = sys.argv[3]
    display_name = sys.argv[4]

    print("Connecting to {} on port {}...".format(server_host, server_port))
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect((server_host, server_port))

    send_message(sock, password + '\n')
    send_message(sock, display_name + '\n')
    welcome_message = receive_message(sock)
    print(welcome_message)

    input_thread = threading.Thread(target=user_input, args=(sock,))
    #Doesn't work
    input_thread.start()

    while True:
        ready_to_read, _, _ = select.select([sock], [], [])
        for source in ready_to_read:
            if source == sock: 
                message = receive_message(sock)
                if not message: 
                    print("Server disconnected.\n")
                    sys.exit(1)
                print(message)

    sock.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And below is my server.py code (Which is where most of my issues remain)

```py
from socket import *
import sys
import threading

clients = []
password = "cs3251"  # Define the password globally

def broadcast(message, sender):
    for client in clients:
        if client != sender:
            client.sendall(message.encode())

def handle_client(client_socket):
    password_attempt = client_socket.recv(1024).strip().decode()
    if password_attempt != password:
        print("Wrong password")
        client_socket.sendall("Wrong password".encode())
        client_socket.close()
        return

    name = client_socket.recv(1024).decode().strip()
    clients.append(client_socket)

    # Send welcome message to the client
    client_socket.sendall(f"Welcome, {name}!\n".encode())
    
    # Notify other clients about the new client joining
    broadcast(f"{name} joined the chatroom\n", client_socket)

    while True:
        message = client_socket.recv(1024).strip().decode()
        if message == ":Exit":
            break  # Exit the loop when receiving the exit command

        if message:
            broadcast("{}: {}\n".format(name, message), client_socket)
        else:
            break

    clients.remove(client_socket)
    broadcast(f"{name} left the chatroom\n", client_socket)
    client_socket.close()

def main():
    port = int(sys.argv[1])
    server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.bind(('', port))
    server_socket.listen(1)
    print("Server started on port " + str(port) + ". Accepting connections...")

    while True:
        client_socket, _ = server_socket.accept()
        message = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
        partition = message.partition('\n')
        name = partition[0].strip()
        password_attempt = partition[2].strip()

        if password_attempt != password:
            client_socket.sendall("Wrong password".encode())
            client_socket.close()
        elif client_socket in clients:
            client_socket.sendall("Name already in use".encode())
            client_socket.close()
        else:
            threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client_socket,)).start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The biggest thing I have been struggling with is
expected 'tester773930 joined the chatroom', got 'None'
File "/autograder/./run_autograder", line 98, in run_test
await start_clients(clients, check_connected)